# flag tooltips vs chart tooltips on highstock

Tags: highcharts

I have a stock chart with the fixed tooltip like the one shown in the stock tooltip positioner example.  Now I want to add some flags on the series.  Each flag's tooltip should be adjacent to the flag when it is "mouse over", like the default positioning/format of a tooltip.  Also, each flag's tooltip has its own text and should not affect the fixed tooltip when displayed (eg. the fixed tooltip would show the stock price and the flag tooltip would show some text associates with the flag)

Do you have any related sample code I can take a look at?  thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly supported but possible to achieve, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/hzYhQ/2/

1) Add custom property for a chart with mouseout/mouseover events for flags:

```
    plotOptions: {
        flags: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function(){
                    this.chart.flagTooltip = true;
                }, 
                mouseOut: function(){
                    this.chart.flagTooltip = false;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Add checking where tooltip should be displayed according to that flag:

```
        positioner: function (w,h,p) {
            var x = 10,
                y = 35;
            if(this.chart.flagTooltip) {
                x = p.plotX;
                y = p.plotY;
            }
            return { x: x, y: y };
        }
```

Comment: Thx for the example.  I was thinking of a solution where a flag has its own tooltip, separate from the series' tooltips.  That way, the tooltip will not appear as jumpy to the users.  Any other workaround?

Comment: Disable tooltip animation.. In Highcharts only one tooltip exists.